# how to present in Jinja2 notation groupedby dataframe to html template in Django

Tags: python, django, dataframe, jinja2

In Django view, via function I prepared dataframe to pass to html template.

```
def owner_observation_count(request):
    form = ReportForm(request.GET)
    context = {}
    if form.is_valid():
        organisation = form.cleaned_data['organisation']
        department_for_report = form.cleaned_data['department_for_report']

        employee_total = Observation.objects.values('owner__last_name','owner__first_name', 'date_created__year','date_created__month').annotate(owner_count_2=Count('owner_id'))

        if organisation:
            employee_total = employee_total.filter(users_organization=organisation)

        if department_for_report:
            employee_total = employee_total.filter(users_department=department_for_report)

        employee_total_pd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(employee_total)
        employee_total_pd["Emploeey"] = employee_total_pd["owner__last_name"].str.cat(' '
                  + employee_total_pd["owner__first_name"].str.get(0) + '.')
        employee_total_pd = employee_total_pd.drop('owner__last_name', axis=1)
        employee_total_pd = employee_total_pd.drop('owner__first_name', axis=1)
        emp_columns = {'date_created__year': 'Year',
                'date_created__month': 'Month',
                'owner_count_2': 'Qty'}
        employee_total_pd.rename(columns=emp_columns, inplace=True)
```

initial result of df looks like this:

[image]

then I grouped dataframe to have result I would like to have:

```
employee_ready_pd = pd.crosstab(employee_total_pd.Emploeey, [employee_total_pd.Year, employee_total_pd.Month],
                    values=employee_total_pd.Qty, aggfunc='sum', margins=True, margins_name="Итого").fillna(0)
```

[image]

then pass it to context

```
context.update({'emp_pd': employee_total_pd})
        context['form'] = form

return render(request, 'observations/reports.html', context)
```

Exactly on this way I would like to have it in HTML page.
How to properly display it via Jinja2 tags?

```
{% for item in emp_pd %}
  ....
{% endfor %}
```

Or may be better, not to group df in function, pass to Jinja previous plain table df and group with the help of jinja tags?

Thanks for advance!